# Minimum Dominating Set

Tags: algorithms, graphs, approximation, set-cover

Consider a graph $G$ with minimum degree $d$, we know through sets cover, it's possible to find the one dominating set $S$ that covers $G$ such that $$S\leq O(\log n)\frac{n}{d}
$$ with high probability, But is it possible to find a deterministic algorithm that achieves this bound in polynomial time?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect this. Also: You are currently asking for the *smallest* dominating set -- an algorithm that finds this in polynomial time would show P=NP. Do you mean you want to find *any* dominating set of size $O(n/d\log n)$? (Also not sure why you write $\frac{n}{d}$ outside the $O(\cdot)$?)

Comment: It would also be helpful to link to the sources you used.

Comment: The greedy set cover algorithm is completely deterministic.

Comment: You write "the one dominating set", but there might be multiple such dominating sets.  Do you mean you want to find any such set?  What algorithm are you thinking of for finding such a set with high probability?